# Unbounded linear operator between normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, linear-transformations, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I am in the middle of a proof and this is one step I don’t understand

Let $T:E\rightarrow F$ be a linear operator between normed spaces $E$ and $F$

If $T$ is unbounded then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $E$ such that $0<||x_n||\leqslant 1$ and $||Tx_n||\geqslant n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Is this trivial. I just don’t see how we can just pick such a sequence.

Comment: $T$ is unbounded iff there is **no** constant $C$ for which you have that $\|T x\|≤ C  \|x\|$ for all $x$. In particular if $T$ is unbounded then for every $n$ there must be a non-zero $x_n$ with $\|T x_n\| ≥  n\|x_n\|$. By rescaling you may assume $\|x_n\|=1$.

Comment: What do you mean by rescaling? How does this imply x_n <= 1?

Comment: I don’t know how you can assume the norm of x_n is 1?

Comment: Suppose $x_n$ is such that $\| Tx_n\|≥ n\ \|x_n\|$ (and $x_n\neq0$). Now define $\tilde x_n := x_n / \|x_n\|$. Check that $\|\tilde x_n\|=1$ and $\|T \tilde x_n\| ≥n$.

Comment: If x_n is negative then choosing 1 will make the rescaled sequence negative too.

Comment: Vector spaces do not in general have a notion of positive or negative vectors. But even if you do have such a structure it is not relevant here. Remember that taking the norm results in a number $≥0$ always.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why is this? Triangle inequality?

Comment: Why the norm is positive? By definition and it is also essential to what the norm is supposed to represent. Very rarely the notion of norm will defined without explicitly stating that it must take on values $≥0$. In my opinion this is _extremely_ bad taste, but you can recover positivity from homogeneity and the triangle inequality: First $\|0\|=0$ by homogeneity, then $0=\|0\| = \|x-x\|≤ \|x\|+\|-x\|=2\|x\|$ for all $x$ by the triangle inequality. Hence $\|x\|≥0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Thank you my notes never defined it to be positive so I forgot this was implied. Thank you this was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since $||T||=\sup_{||x||= 1} ||T(x)||$, for every natural number $n$ there exist an $x_n$ so that $||x_n||= 1$ and $||T(x_n)||\geq n$.